# How to pass multiple parameters using web-api

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass two params using json in web-api, but I get null each time I try, what am I missing ? is there a better way to pass more than one parameter?

//HTML

```
var uri = "api/Login";
```

//after I click a button this function fires

```
function checkUser() {
        var email = "ttt@ggg.com";   
       var password = "itsme";
          var details = "{ email:'"+ email+"', pass:'"+ password+"'}";           
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",          
            data: JSON.stringify(details),
            url: uri,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

// LoginController

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromBody]string  data)
{
     HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
     //the code run this function, but the 'data' is null
     string userinfo = data;                    
     return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[FromBody]` attribute won't work on `GET` requests because there is no body in a `GET` request.

You must either pass the values as parameters or change the method to `[HttpPost]`. I suggest you change the method to `[HttpPost]` and change your `ajax` request method to `POST`.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromBody]string  data)
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
    //the code run this function, but the 'data' is null
    string userinfo = data;                    
    return msg;
}
```

and in your `ajax` request

```
function checkUser() {
    var email = "ttt@ggg.com";   
    var password = "itsme";
      var details = "{ email:'"+ email+"', pass:'"+ password+"'}";           
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",          
        data: JSON.stringify(details),
        url: uri,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}
```

Comment: What would the `uri` look like?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GET vs. POST issue noted by @su8898, you are already building a string in `details` and then trying to `stringify` it.  You should define details as object literal like this:

```
var details = {
    'email': email,
    'pass': password
};
```

This would give you an actual object to `stringify`.